# How to disable the transition of fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, transition

I am building a quiz app with three questions and therefore I have 6 Fragments but I would like to disable the default transition from one fragment to another, how can I achieve this? I already disabled that you can swipe between the fragments, you have to click a button to get to the next fragment, but there is still somehow a swiping transition after clicking the button. I searched for this but there was never an answer that would fit my problem. Here is one fragment example:

```
public class FragmentQuestion1 extends Fragment {

private Button btnNavFrag1;
private EditText editText;
private ProgressBar m_bar;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable       ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_1, container, false);

btnNavFrag1 = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_question1);

editText = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_question_1);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcher(editText));

m_bar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_question_1);





btnNavFrag1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        ((GameActivity)getActivity()).setViewPager(2);

    }
});

return view;
 }

 // Method that is used so the countdown starts when the user gets to               this fragment
 @Override
 public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
if (visible) {
    startCountdownTimer();
}
 }

  // Countdown 17 seconds

int i = 0;


private void startCountdownTimer() {

m_bar.setProgress(i);

final int totalMsecs = 17 * 1000; // 17 seconds in milli seconds
int callInterval = 100;

/** CountDownTimer */
new CountDownTimer(totalMsecs, callInterval) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        int secondsRemaining = (int) millisUntilFinished / 1000;

        float fraction = millisUntilFinished / (float) totalMsecs;

        // progress bar is based on scale of 1 to 100;
        m_bar.setProgress((int) (fraction * 100));
    }

    public void onFinish() {
    }
}.start();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a viewPager, you could use a library like [this](https://github.com/geftimov/android-viewpager-transformers) which lets you add a transformer (some sort of effect) to the viewPager when going to the next fragment. I'd recommend the [ZoomOutTranformer](https://github.com/geftimov/android-viewpager-transformers/wiki/ZoomOutTranformer) for your use-case. If the transition is not what you expect you can always extend from that class and override the transition so it's more to your liking.

ViewPagerTransformers are native, so you don't need to use a library. Just create a class, implement the `PageTransformer` interface and override the method `transformPage`.

Comment: I don't want any transition. The thing is that the fragment 1 is the same as fragment 2, except there are two other textviews, so when I click on the button in fragment one I just want the textviews to disappear. I can only achieve this when there is no transition

Comment: Aha, in that case you could take a look at `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition()`. Using that you can have a layout with different 'scenes' and transition between them, hiding and showing different views when needed. If this seems to be more what you need I'll add it as a new answer and in more detail. More info can be found at https://developer.android.com/training/transitions#java

Answer (score 0):

In your layout xml define a tablayout and a FrameLayout like this:

```
        ..................your xml code...............

 .............................................................   

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/simpleTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#0080FF"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#050505"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/abcd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 1" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="item 2" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="item 3" />
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>



        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/simpleFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

This layout is defined for three tabs. You can make it for more tabs by adding more tabs if you like.

Then define the fragments for each tab. In this case:
item_one_fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="your.activity.context">

    ......................................
............................................
fragments xml 
.............................
,.....................................

</RelativeLayout>
```

Similarly item 2 and item 3 fragment layouts.

Then define the fragments in java:

```
public class FirstItemFragment extends Fragment {

    public ListView CallListView;

    public FirstFragment() {
// Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_one_fragment, container, false);


// Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;

    }




}
```

Simiarly second and third fragment.

Then in your Main Activity:

```
FrameLayout simpleFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.simpleFrameLayout);
       TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.simpleTabLayout);


        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, new FirstItemFragment());
        ft.commit();


        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                // get the current selected tab's position and replace the fragment accordingly
                Fragment fragment = null;
                switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        fragment = new FirstItemFragment();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fragment = new SecondItemFragment();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        fragment = new ThirdItemFragment();
                        break;
                }

                getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                //Commit the transaction.
                .commit();

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

Now when you run your activity you will have three tabs and when you click on any one you will go to the respective fragment without any swipe

Comment: But I don't want Tabs in my layout. The user flow would be: Question 1 Fragment --> button click --> answer 1 Fragment which looks like question 1 fragment but has an extra TextView and another button

Comment: you can completely change each fragment layout top to bottom as you like(height, width included). The only thing difficult to change will be the tabs themselves.

Comment: If you do not want tabs, you can use buttons with the same code.